# Numpy efficient one against all

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array 3xN of 3d coordinates and I would like to efficiently calculate a distance matrix of all entries.
Is there any efficient loop strategy rather than the nested loop one could apply?

Current pseudocode implementation:

```
for i,coord in enumerate(coords):
    for j,coords2 in enumerate(coords):
        if i != j:
             dist[i,j] = numpy.norm(coord - coord2)
```

Comment: Use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist).

Answer (score 5):

To reproduce your results exactly:

```
>>> import scipy.spatial as sp
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.rand(5,3) #Note this is the transpose of your array.
>>> a
array([[ 0.83921304,  0.72659404,  0.50434178],  #0
       [ 0.99883826,  0.91739731,  0.9435401 ],  #1
       [ 0.94327962,  0.57665875,  0.85853404],  #2
       [ 0.30053567,  0.44458829,  0.35677649],  #3
       [ 0.01345765,  0.49247883,  0.11496977]]) #4
>>> sp.distance.cdist(a,a)
array([[ 0.        ,  0.50475862,  0.39845025,  0.62568048,  0.94249268],
       [ 0.50475862,  0.        ,  0.35554966,  1.02735895,  1.35575051],
       [ 0.39845025,  0.35554966,  0.        ,  0.82602847,  1.1935422 ],
       [ 0.62568048,  1.02735895,  0.82602847,  0.        ,  0.3783884 ],
       [ 0.94249268,  1.35575051,  1.1935422 ,  0.3783884 ,  0.        ]])
```

To do it more efficiently without duplicating calculations and only calculate unique pairs:

```
>>> sp.distance.pdist(a)
array([ 0.50475862,  0.39845025,  0.62568048,  0.94249268,  0.35554966,
        1.02735895,  1.35575051,  0.82602847,  1.1935422 ,  0.3783884 ])
#pairs: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3),
#         (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Note the relationship between the two arrays. The `cdist` array can be reproduced by:

```
>>> out=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[0]))
>>> dists=sp.distance.pdist(a)
>>> out[np.triu_indices(a.shape[0],1)]=dists
>>> out+=out.T

>>> out
array([[ 0.        ,  0.50475862,  0.39845025,  0.62568048,  0.94249268],
       [ 0.50475862,  0.        ,  0.35554966,  1.02735895,  1.35575051],
       [ 0.39845025,  0.35554966,  0.        ,  0.82602847,  1.1935422 ],
       [ 0.62568048,  1.02735895,  0.82602847,  0.        ,  0.3783884 ],
       [ 0.94249268,  1.35575051,  1.1935422 ,  0.3783884 ,  0.        ]])
```

---

Some somewhat surprising timings-

The setup:

```
def pdist_toarray(a):
    out=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[0]))
    dists=sp.distance.pdist(a)

    out[np.triu_indices(a.shape[0],1)]=dists
    return out+out.T

def looping(a):
    out=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[0]))
    for i in xrange(a.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(a.shape[0]):
            out[i,j]=np.linalg.norm(a[i]-a[j])
    return out
```

Timings:

```
arr=np.random.rand(1000,3)

%timeit sp.distance.pdist(arr)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.26 ms per loop

%timeit sp.distance.cdist(arr,arr)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.31 ms per loop

%timeit pdist_toarray(arr)
10 loops, best of 3: 66.2 ms per loop

%timeit looping(arr)
1 loops, best of 3: 16.7 s per loop
```

So if you want the square array back you should use `cdist` if you just want the pairs use `pdist`. Looping is ~4000x slower for an array with 1000 elements and ~70x slower for an array with 10 elements compared to `cdist`.

Comment: Scipy provides the [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) function to convert between the vector and matrix versions of the distance array (the "condensed" and "redundant" forms)